# how can get the date in this format "31-jun-2013"

Tags: c#, date, format

how can i get the date in this format "30-jun-2013"

at runtime if user type in the above format in the textbox ..it will fetch the matching rows of data for the specified date and filter that and show in datagridview

so for that i want to compare the date format with the text typed in textbox

```
string todaydate = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Today);

DateTime DTM = Convert.ToDateTime(todaydate);

string datetoday = DTM.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");

if (TypeHereTextBox.Text == datetoday)

{
    OLCMND2 = new OracleCommand("Select * from TABLENAME where DATE = '" +              typeHereTextBox.Text + "'", CON);

    OADAP1 = new OracleDataAdapter(OLCMND2);
    OADAP1.Fill(DTBLE2);

    DatagridView.DataSource = DTBLE2;
}
```

how can it be solved

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Have a look at TryParse, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx

Comment: Convert the textBox content to a date and compare that to todays date.  Be aware that the MMM in dd-MMM-yyyy is culture dependent.

Comment: what is the database type of `DATE` column?

Comment: @Damith it is DATE datetype using Oracle 11g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi i got the solution guys

```
string[] arrayData = TextBox.Text.Split('-');

if (arrayData.Length == 3)

OLCMND2 = new OracleCommand("Select VISITORCOUNT,REMARKS,to_date(to_char(TODAYDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YYYY') AS TODAYDATE,CARDNUMBER,PHOTO from VMS_VISITOR where TODAYDATE = TO_DATE('" + TypeHereTextBox.Text + "','dd-MON-yyyy')", CON);

OADAP1 = new OracleDataAdapter(OLCMND2);
OADAP1.Fill(DTBLE2);

DatagridView.DataSource = DTBLE2;
```

Thanks for all your responses guys

Answer (score 0):

first of all you are doing string compare, which means you compare the references. please use

```
if (TypeHereTextBox.Text.Equals(datetoday))
```

instead.

second, why not comparing dateTime and not strings?
because your data isn't a valid date anyway then you can't use `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` but woth any valid date you can do:

```
DateTime d;
DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "dd-MMM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out d);

if (d== DTM)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will parse from that format:

```
var dateToParse = "30-Jun-2013"; //TypeHereTextBox.Text
var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateToParse, "dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

if (parsedDate.Date == datetoday.Date)
{
    // Do stuff
```

note - June only has 30 days ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be check for date month and year separately with the today's date. if it matches , then concatenate the date month and year in the format you want and pass to the query.

Answer (score 0):

I would not compare date as strings, fist convert string to DateTime using `DateTime.ParseExact` by giving datetime format string. then compare two datetime objects instead of string comparison.

And also I would use parameters to set the Date column value as below

```
OLCMND2 = new OracleCommand("Select * from TABLENAME where DATE = :dateVal", CON);
OLCMND2.Parameters.Add("dateVal", OracleDbType.Date
     , myDatetime, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input);
```